# Capsuling a webworker fails

Tags: javascript, class, web-worker

I would like to capsule a webworker so that I can easily reuse it in other projects.

This is what I did. However I am getting the error message:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

But when I comment the code line `this.worker = new Worker(workerPath);` in `Heartbeat.js` this code does not cause any trouble.

What is wrong here?

my index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js/script.js:

```
import * as Heartbeat from "./Heartbeat.js";

var hb = new Heartbeat.Heartbeat("MyHeartbeat");
```

and js/Heartbeat.js

```
export class Heartbeat {

    constructor(name, workerPath="js/Heartbeat.js") {
        this.name = name;
        this.worker = new Worker(workerPath);
    }

    sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }

    async start_heartbeat() {
        counter = 0;
        while(true) {
            counter++;
            console.log("counter = " + counter)
            await sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `new Worker(workerPath, {type:'module'})`?

Comment: Hey, no I just tried. Now I am getting the error ` TypeError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Module scripts are not supported on DedicatedWorker yet. You can try the feature with '--enable-experimental-web-platform-features' flag (see https://crbug.com/680046)`